# Get latitude and longitude from json data

Tags: java, android, json

How to fetch latitude and longitude  from this json data in java?

```
{
"cloc": {
    "cid": 1001,
    "latlong": [
        {
            "lat": 23.2331,
            "lon": 43.23
        },
        {
            "lat": 44.322,
            "lon": 93.423
        },
        {
            "lat": 44.322,
            "lon": 93.423
        }
    ]
}
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to parse JSON in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2591098/how-to-parse-json-in-java)

Comment: The lat is 23.2331 and the lon is 43.23. (Looks like Saudi Arabia)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with below code:

```
JSONObject object = new JSONObject(YOUR RESPONSE STRING);

JSONArray jArray = object.getJSONArray("latlong");

for (int i = 0; i < jArray.length(); i++)
{
    String lat = jArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("lat");
    String lon = jArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("lon");

}
```

Comment: Exception in thread "main" org.json.JSONException: JSONObject["latlong"] not found.
 at org.json.JSONObject.get(JSONObject.java:454)
 at org.json.JSONObject.getJSONArray(JSONObject.java:535)
 at com.tatya.JsonReader.main(JsonReader.java:45)

Comment: @Rah show me how you have implemented?

Comment: How you have wrote this line in your code : JSONObject object = new JSONObject(YOUR RESPONSE STRING);

Comment: JSONObject object = readJsonFromUrl("http://192.168.0.10:8080/project/Child?id1=1001");public static JSONObject readJsonFromUrl(String url) throws IOException, JSONException 
  {
    InputStream is = new URL(url).openStream();
     try 
     {
      BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, Charset.forName("UTF-8")));
      String jsonText = readAll(rd);
      JSONObject json = new JSONObject(jsonText);
      //JSONArray json = new JSONArray(jsonText);
      return json;
     }

Comment: @Rah its not the issue in my code, you are doing something wrong, please check it out.

Comment: I tried this one object.getJSONObject("cloc").getJSONArray("latlong").getJSONObject(1) but it gives me only {"lon":93.423,"lat":44.322} and i need lat and long

Comment: @Rah yah then you are going on right way. JSONArray json =  object.getJSONObject("cloc").getJSONArray("latlong"); 
Then, go with for loop as I have posted in my answer.

Comment: Why this exception is happening org.json.JSONException: JSONObject["lat"] not a string. do you have some clue. please

Comment: Try with this way : object.getJSONObject("cloc").getJSONArray("latlong").getJSONObject(1).getString("lat"); and tell me is it working or not?

Comment: String lat = json.getJSONObject(i).get("lat").toString();
Thanks a lot, Finalyy its worked for me

Comment: @Rah I am asking that is it working or not? " not its working." means?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your data is already a parsed `JSONObject`, you can use:

```
JSONData.getJSONObject("cloc").getJSONArray("latlong").getJSONObject(i).getString("lat")
```

and:

```
JSONData.getJSONObject("cloc").getJSONArray("latlong").getJSONObject(i).getString("lon")
```

iterating over all the values of `i` in the range from 0 till the length of the `latlong` array.

Comment: I tried this one object.getJSONObject("cloc").getJSONArray("latlong").getJSONObject(1) but it gives me only {"lon":93.423,"lat":44.322} and i need lat and long